# A semisimple Lie group has no character; Am I right?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a compact connected Lie group with semisimple Lie algebra ${\frak g}$. With the following reasoning, I show that there is no non-trivial Lie group homomorphism
$$\chi:G\to S^1.$$
Is that true?

---

*Proof.* Let $\chi:G\to S^1\subseteq\Bbb C$ be a character. Then, $d\chi:{\frak g}\to i\Bbb R$ so $id\chi:{\frak g}\to \Bbb R$, i.e. $id\chi\in{\frak g}^*$. But since $\chi$ is a homomorphism, and $S^1$ is abelian, we have for all $g\in G$ and $X\in{\frak g}$ that
$$({\operatorname{Ad}}_g^*id\chi)(X)=i\frac{d}{dt}\Big|_{t=0}\chi(\exp(t\operatorname{Ad}_{g^{-1}}(X)))=i\frac{d}{dt}\Big|_{t=0}\chi(g^{-1}\exp(tX)g)=i\frac{d}{dt}\chi(\exp(tX))=id\chi(X).$$
Thus, $\operatorname{Ad}_g^*id\chi=id\chi$ for all $g\in G$. Using the Killing form to identify $id\chi\in{\frak g}^*$ with an element $X_{\chi}\in{\frak g}$, we find $\operatorname{Ad}_g(X_{\chi})=X_{\chi}$ for all $g\in G$. Thus, $X_{\chi}\in\operatorname{Lie}(Z_G)=Z_{{\frak g}}$ (where $Z$ means "center"). But a semisimple Lie algebra has zero center and hence $X_{\chi}=0$. Thus, $id\chi=0$ and hence $\chi=1$. $$\tag{Q.E.D.}$$

Comment: The group has to be connected, for otherwise this is false. Take any compact $G$ and consider the Lie group $G\times\mathbb Z/7\mathbb Z$. It admits a non-trivial homomorphism to $S^1$.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Right! I was using this assumption to deduce $d\chi=0$ $\implies$ $\chi =1$. Thanks!

Comment: You should have a question on [Ado's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ado%27s_theorem), right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The character $\chi$ induces a morphism $f:g\rightarrow R$, since $g$ is semi-simple, $[g,g]=g$, but the restriction of $f$ to $[g,g]$ is zero since $f([x,y])=[f(x),f(y)]=0$, thus $f=0$.

Answer (score 0):

If $\chi$ is a group homomorphism, then its differential at the identity is a Lie algebra homomorphism $f:\mathfrak g\to\mathbb R$. If $f$ is not zero, then its kernel $K$ is an ideal in $\mathfrak g$ which, as the algebra is semisimple, has a complement, that is, there is another ideal $L$ in $\mathfrak g$ such that $\mathfrak g=K\oplus L$. The ideal $L$ is one dimensional, because $f$ induces an isomorhism $\mathfrak g/K\to\mathbb R$. Now an ideal of a semisimple Lie algebra is itself a semisimple Lie algebra, and therefore it is impossible for $L$ be one-dimensional.

What happens if $f$ is zero (and $G$ connected, as it should be)?

Comment: Just to be clear: The answer is yes and you are giving a second proof different from mine?